# Can't detect every type of object in Winforms controls

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

So, after using C#, I started learning C++. Microsoft.NET is one of my favorite frameworks, and I love using it in both C# and C++. I am trying to make a maze/shooter game but I have some problems with controls. To detect collision detection I use this:

```
void check_col(Object^sender, EventArgs^e)
    {
        if((Sprites::character->Location.X == (Tiles::wall1->Location.X - 15))
            && (Sprites::character->Location.Y >= Tiles::wall1->Location.Y) 
            && (Sprites::character->Location.Y <= Tiles::wall1->Location.Y + 15))
        {
            col_right = true;
            System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("We Have A Collision");
        }
        else {col_right = false;}
    }
```

I could specifically ask about collision detection, but this works fine for me. The code is important when asking the "wall1" location. The problem is that it only detects the last wall being drawn into the screen. Well, I use the following code to draw everything in the screen:

```
int tilex = 0;
        int tiley = 0;
        for(int row = 0; row < 20; row++)
        {
            for(int column = 0; column < 20; column++)
            {
                switch(map[row][column])
                {
                case 0: make_wall1(); 
                    Tiles::wall1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(tilex, tiley);
                    this->Controls->Add(Tiles::wall1);
                    Tiles::wall1->BringToFront();
                }
                tilex += 15;
                if(column == 19)
                {
                    tiley += 15;
                    tilex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

**So my question is: How can I get all "wall" locations?!**

**NOTE: Sometimes in these pieces of code you'll see 15, that's because walls are 15x15p tiles.**

Comment: it seems to me your code is messy. it looks like you are overwriting the wall1 member, thus killing the every wall but the last one, and that's why you can't check collision to any wall but the last one

Comment: It doesn't work right because you only have a single "wall" control.  One you add over and over again, which has no effect.  You'll need to use the *gcnew* operator to create a new instance of the control.  Using hundreds of controls in a window and hard-coding sizes are not very good practices.

Comment: Hans Passant- Can you show me an example in code?